# Ansible permission problems

Tags: ansible

I have seen this a lot on this forum but none of the answers have helped me.

I am trying to run an ansible playbook, this worked fine on my Debian PC. Now I have moved to Ubuntu 16.04 it's not working. I get permission denied public key errors.

I am assuming this is because I am running sudo ansible-playbook.

This would then try to use the public key from my root user which is not on the servers I am trying to ansible.

How do I run an ansible-playbook as sudo but use the ssh keys from my current user?

If I run as sudo I get

```
fatal: [10.11.8.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

If I don't run as sudo I get

```
fatal: [10.11.8.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Cannot write to ControlPath /home/chrisl/.ansible/cp"}
```

[WARNING]: Could not create retry file '/home/chrisl/ansible/keys.retry'.
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/chrisl/ansible/keys.retry'

I have also tried this and you can see what happens....

[image: Picture Here with errors]

Comment: It appaers in the second example that your "chrisl" user account can't fully read/write/update the '/home/chrisl/ansible/keys.retry' file.  Can you confirm that your "chrisl" account can view/read/write that file?  I don't think this is directly related to your question, but it might impact it later.

Comment: Is this really ansible issue? You clearly have some permissions problems on your chris account. You might want to try -H flag for sudo.

Answer (score 3):

AFTER you ran the 1st command `ansible-playbook` as user `root`, from your user `chris`, that execution left (create) files that belong to the user `root` under the home folder of `chris`. Then next run as user `chris` fails to modify files that belong to `root`.

What you should do is:

- Determine which ssh methodology you want/need to use here - ssh-agent, or passwordless default ssh key, b/c the 1st command failed due to key problem. you also can pass parameter `--private-key=/path/to/key`, if it is passwordless.
- Fix: As user `root` make ALL files under `/home/chris` belong to user `chris` and its default group: `sudo chown -R chris:chris /home/chris`
- if you have a lot of data the above command may take some time
- run your playbooks from the specific, same user, and don't mix. if you're mixing - learn how to do it properly.
- learn/read/experiment about unix permissions, identity switching, environment, etc., b/c this is not a case of "ansible permissions" problem, but "chris understanding unix permissions" problem, which is OK, given you're just beginning with unix/linux

Good luck.